# Having trouble Parenting a Bezier curve

Tags: animation, inverse-kinematics, splines

So I am working on a mesh of a character with a tail. I used a Bezier curve to IK that but I'm having trouble. Everything is fine until I try to parent the curve to the armature in some what either the whole thing or a specefic bone. When I do just one bone at the base of the tail and try to use the handle on the end of the curve at the tail bones base it causes the whole curve to rotate at the handle, and I can't get it not to do that.
Here is my blend file
[image]

Here are thimages that were requested.

The first it the Curve being bent when not parented to the armature. As you can see working perfectly.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqe1I.jpg

The second is after the curve is parented to the first bone of the tail and then the handle is used. Instead of curving it spins the whole curve wildly twisting it up.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pPFM.jpg

Comment: Please place an image in your question.

Comment: See Spline IK .. for more control and then show your work.

Comment: Okay added the images

Comment: I still really need help on this, I have looked everywhere for an answer.